# Processing data sent from drupal 7 webform

Tags: webforms, theming

I've inserted a webform in a node's template like so:

`<?php print render($content['webform']); ?>`

and created the webform in the admin panel for that page. The form shows up fine and I've styled it correctly. I would now like to know the Drupal way of grabbing the data from the form. Most likely a preprosses function from what I've researched.

The form is very simple, just an email address and a submit button. I'm good with PHP but still getting used to drupal's backend functionality.  Any help or direction is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Update - I've noticed there is a admin section in the webform panel that allows me to send it to an email address. However, I would still like to know how to do this manually with some type of function. As ill also have to send another email out to the user.

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear about your question. But here is the answer from what i understood.

Try creating a new module and use the hooks to process the data 
http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/group/webform_hooks/7

Comment: Thanks, I would like to learn that way for sure but think it might be a bit overkill for now given my current knowledge of Drupal. To make it simpler, I'd like to put a very simple form on a page. Grab the information from the form, and send it to the webmaster and the user. Cheers.

Comment: @James Billings - By default the webform has options for doing it. check its options.