# extracting data from webform and parsing it

Tags: webforms

I looked into [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/processing-data-sent-from-drupal-7-webform) question, but it was irrelevant.

I have data entries on my webform... obviously each field has its own key field. Let's say it has key1, key2, key 3

What I want to do is to create an email draft as such:

---

Hi "key1"

I wanted to say "key2"

**SUBMIT BUTTON**

---

After pressing the submit button it will be emailed to "key3"

---

If there isn't any module that does do this, then can anyone tell me the steps( doesn't have to be very detailed) needed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use token for that purpose. Webform do have a facility to add token in mail template. But this would be default mail template using dynamic value of submitted form.

There you can find all field component available in webform.[image]

Comment: I had major issues with my server...sorry I couldn't get to you earlier; I think you didn't understand my question clearly... I don't want to send a confirmation message... rather after filling the form... I want a draft to be created which after hitting a submit button...that draft would be emailed to 'key3'... what you are offering is only how to customize the confirmation message that the applicant will see after filling the data on his/her screen without any email being sent to 'key3'...Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If ultimate objective is to send email to key3, then you should be able to use value of any field which is key3 in your case, you will find that under email settings of webform.